# Leaflet Buffer value by GeoJSON feature.properties

Tags: leaflet, geojson, buffer, markers

Is it possible to add a buffer to a list of points, taking the value of the radius from the properties of the GeoJSON file?

This is my code to take points from JSON files and represent them as cluster markers. I would like to add a buffer equal to the value of the buffer property in the JSON file to the points. I searched the turf documentation but didn't find something like this.

```
var Ar_clusters = L.markerClusterGroup();   
$.getJSON('a.json', function(data) {
  var Arc = L.geoJson(data, {
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
      return L.marker(latlng, {
      icon: L.icon({
        iconUrl: "img/ar.png",
        iconSize: [40, 40],
        iconAnchor: [12, 28],
        popupAnchor: [0, -25]
      }),
      title: feature.properties.name,
      riseOnHover: true
    });
  },
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            if (feature.properties) {
      var content = "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed'>" + "<tr><th>Name</th><td>" + feature.properties.name + "</td></tr>" + "<tr><th>Info</th><td>" + feature.properties.popupinfo + "</td></tr>" + "<table>";
      layer.on({
        click: function (e) {
          $("#feature-title").html(feature.properties.name);
          $("#feature-info").html(content);
          $("#featureModal").modal("show");
          highlight.clearLayers().addLayer(L.circleMarker([feature.geometry.coordinates[1], feature.geometry.coordinates[0]], highlightStyle));
        }
      });
      $("#feature-list tbody").append('<tr class="feature-row" id="' + L.stamp(layer) + '" lat="' + layer.getLatLng().lat + '" lng="' + layer.getLatLng().lng + '"><td style="vertical-align: middle;"><img width="16" height="18" src="assets/img/ar.png"></td><td class="feature-name">' + layer.feature.properties.name + '</td><td style="vertical-align: middle;"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i></td></tr>');
      ArSearch.push({
        name: layer.feature.properties.name,
        address: layer.feature.properties.ADDRESS1,
        source: "Ar",
        id: L.stamp(layer),
        lat: layer.feature.geometry.coordinates[1],
        lng: layer.feature.geometry.coordinates[0]
      });
      }
      layer.addTo(Ar_clusters);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'buffer'? If you mean circle around marker point with desired radius in meters, you can use vector layer `L.circle` object for that.

Comment: tnx @TomazicM in that way works `  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
   if (feature.properties.buffer) {
          return new L.Circle(latlng, feature.properties.buffer);
        } else {
    return L.marker(latlng, {
      icon: L.icon({
        iconUrl: "assets/img/ar.png",
        iconSize: [40, 40],
        iconAnchor: [12, 28],
        popupAnchor: [0, -25]
      }),
      title: feature.properties.name,
      riseOnHover: true
    })};`

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you solved your problem with `L.Circle` class?